# SQL order by in union all query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query which produces following below data.
All I want to show list of users in Alphabetically order and First Record should be All , All.

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT 'All' created_by,
       'All' Prepby
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
       to_char(d.created_by) AS created_by,
       get_user_name(d.created_by) Prepby
FROM Hpml_Gp_dtl d
WHERE d.created_by IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: If you are using the result of this query to put in a dropdown list (eg), then you would be better off adding the "All, All" record to the list in code, rather than trying to do it in the database.

Comment: Since `All` is alphabetically after `ABDUL`, then you need a different order key don't you? Can you imagine how you would do that? You'd need to add another column to order by, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`.

**Query**

```
select t.* from (
    select 'All' created_by, 'All' Prepby
    from dual
    union all
    select distinct to_char(d.created_by) as created_by,
    get_user_name(d.created_by) Prepby
    from Hpml_Gp_dtl d
    where d.created_by is not null
) t
order by case Prepby when 'All' then 1 else 2 end, Prepby;
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out the need to turn the original SELECT into an inline view. When the query is a UNION of select statements we cannot reference column by name without doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the `ORDER BY` in a sub-query:

```
SELECT 'All' AS created_by,
       'All' AS Prepby
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         to_char(created_by),
         get_user_name(created_by)
  FROM   Hpml_Gp_dtl
  WHERE  created_by IS NOT null
  ORDER BY 2
)
```